# html5 or xaml for windows 8 / 8.1

Tags: html, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am new to app development and chose C# and xaml for apps. But things didnt quite go well. I aint a full time programming freak; can just manage an hour or two a day after college studies and with xaml my head really hurts.
Recently i came to know that even html5 can be used to make apps. So my question is this :

Should i continue with xaml or switch to html5 ?

Ref : http://devchic.azurewebsites.net/?p=581

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147012/should-i-choose-html5-or-xaml-for-metro-development

My requirements are :

1) Shouldn't be too time consuming

2) I will currently focus on light and simple apps ( Games maybe, but not in near future)

3) They should be available to both wp8 as well as desktop, and if possible to other platforms as well.

(I happen to know c++ and Java at intermediate level.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While either solution could work, here are some things to consider.  *I'm going to assume you mean Windows Store applications when you said "desktop."*

> 1) Shouldn't be too time consuming

That's very difficult to say. If you're not familiar with C# and Xaml, there will be a learning curve. You mentioned you know Java though, so the language shouldn't be too much of a challenge. If you're interested in quick to build, I'd suggest you start with Xaml and C# and use the Xaml visual designer to gain some experience and ignore the Xaml output at first. By default, like a web page, the layout system is not absolute and often uses various types of panels (grids, dock panel, etc.) for layout.

Microsoft has a lot of great examples on MSDN that would allow you to both learn more about your options, but even contrast the coding techniques. Having taught someone at work in a little more than an hour how to get started and be productive, you might want to give Xaml another go.

> 2) I will currently focus on light and simple apps ( Games maybe, but not in near future)

Your definition of light and simple isn't specified. You could create applications that meet that requirement with either platform. If you're building games, the answer changes and becomes more complex. As you're still learning though, I'll not talk about that here.

> 3) They should be available to both wp8 as well as desktop, and if possible to other platforms as well.

Today, there are 4 common ways of developing an application for Windows 8.1 desktop:

1. Xaml/C# (C++ is also an option here)
2. WinJS/HTML/JavaScript (WinJS is a Windows store application-only framework)
3. Either of the above, hosting a web page (either from a web server or local in-app)
4. C++/DirectX (for games)

Currently, there isn't a way to use WinJS or the same code for option 4 on Windows Phone. So, you'd likely narrow your options to Xaml or a web page view. While you can't take Xaml and necessarily use the same Xaml on both platforms, the patterns and development experience are very close. By using a "portable class library", it's now possible to share the common business logic between the platforms.

A Xaml approach would allow, without extra effort, the application to be a native experience. Th application would have the appearance and behaviors of a Windows Store application. If you went with just an embedded web page approach, you'd be on your own. I will not take on the experience and look of Windows. If you aren't familiar with doing reasonably complex HTML and CSS, an embedded web page solution may be too time consuming.

> (I happen to know c++ and Java at intermediate level.)

Here's a few links that might help you:

- [Getting started developing apps for Windows Phone and Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714071%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
- [Develop Windows Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229519.aspx)

This will likely help you with either choice.

#### Traditional Windows Desktop applications

If you want to build a traditional Windows desktop application and not a Store application, your options are similar, with the exception that you might choose to build your application using WPF. windows Presentation Foundation was the predecessor to the Xaml used in Windows Phone and Store applications. It's not identical, but the knowledge of one transfers well. You can also host an web page inside of a "desktop" application. I've done it frequently. If you're trying to build someone "modern" though, learn the Windows Store frameworks.

Comment: I'll take it in favor of xaml then i guess. I already have subscribed for " Wp8 dev for absolute beg " series on MVA( half way through, and stuck !). Any other resources ( preferably videos) for using xaml( complete noobs) for wp8 you know of ? Is head first c# good in that regards ?

Comment: You could read [Essential Windows Phone 8](http://www.amazon.com/Essential-Windows-Edition-Microsoft-Development/dp/032190494X) It covers xaml before it delves on the WP Platform.

Answer (score 1):

If XAML hurts, I say go HTML5. I don't understand XAML very well myself, so I use HTML5 for my Win8 apps.

Regarding your requirements, HTML5 fits 1&2 perfectly. It's not very common to write desktop apps in HTML5 though, so your options there will be quite limited.

Comment: can you be a little more specific considering all the requirements ?

Comment: By "common to write", do you mean that  is it difficult to write apps in html5 for desktop, or it's not a common practice ? Any reasons for your answer ? And by req. 1) I mean " should be easy to learn and productive at the same time". Is that what u mean ? It shouldn't be that i switch now only to realize later that html5 aint too productive. ( BTW m itching to make anything good )

Comment: You cannot write desktop apps with HTML5. Only Windows Phone 8/8.1 and Windows 8/8.1 apps.